# MagicalRecord - wrong data after save

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord

@Edit
@PangHoMing - I'll do it step by step once again.
First of all setup - following your suggestion

```
    MagicalRecord.setLoggingLevel(.verbose)
    MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack(withAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed: dataStack)
```

Next data save method:

```
     MagicalRecord.save({ (context) in
         _ = data(context)
     }) { (success, error) in
         completion(success,error)
     }
```

I'm using `CoreDataEditor` to preview entities. After performing this part everything seems to be fine.

Cart create closure (I just removed part responsible for specific fields to shorten message)

```
  let createCart: (NSManagedObjectContext) -> () = {context in
            let offlineCart = Cart.mr_createEntity(in: context)!
            offlineCart.code = "0"
```

Next I'm getting cart data back to return it. Also as you suggested without using specific context

```
    let cart: Cart? = Cart.mr_findFirst()
```

Now lets add sth to my cart here starts some problematic part

```
      let addEntry: (NSManagedObjectContext) -> () = { context in
        if let entry = CartEntry.mr_findFirst(with: NSPredicate(format: "product.code == %@", productCode), in: context) {
            entry.quantity = NSNumber.init(value: (entry.quantity?.intValue)! + 1)
        } else {
            let entry = CartEntry.mr_createEntity(in: context)!
            entry.quantity = quantity
            entry.product = Product.mr_findFirst(with: NSPredicate(format: "code == %@", productCode), in: context)
            entry.code = productCode
            entry.cart = Cart.mr_findFirst(in: context)
        }
    }
```

As you can see code above is trying to find existing `CartEntry` if found it's just increasing quantity, if not it's creating new `CartEntry` related to `Cart` and `Product`. Why there are `in: context`? Cause when I omit them save is not performing. I've got a warnings like:`NO CHANGES IN ** saveWithBlock:completion: ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING`

Till now everything seems to be ok. `CoreDataEditor` shows structure like this 
[image: CoreDataStructure]

Now let's move to delete operation.

**Attempt 1** - remove closure passed to save method (as above)

```
        let removeEntry: (NSManagedObjectContext) -> () = { context in
            CartEntry.mr_deleteAll(matching: NSPredicate(format: "product.code == %@", product.code), in: context)
        }

        self.coreDataManager.saveData(data: removeEntry, completion: { (succes, error) in
            completion(succes, error)
        })
```

**Effect 1:** 
Completions block returns `success = true, error = nil` Right after this operations we're refreshing cart with 
`let cart: Cart? = Cart.mr_findFirst()` - cart.entries field got 2 `CartEntry` objects ignoring fact that I just deleted one. What is more app crashes because received entry (one that supposed to be deleted) do not have related `Product`. `CoreDataEditor` shows only 1 entry. After restarting applications cart is once again correct - got only 1 entry, without data I just deleted.

**Attempt 2:** 
Let's ignore `in: context`

`let removeEntry: (NSManagedObjectContext) -> () = { context in
    CartEntry.mr_deleteAll(matching: NSPredicate(format: "product.code == %@", product.code))
}`

**Effect 2:** 
`NO CHANGES IN ** saveWithBlock:completion: ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING`

**Solution**

Double check your `Delete rules` - the problem was `No Action` instead of `Nullify`

Answer (score 0):

The `MagicalRecord.save` is saving data to `defaultContext`

```
MagicalRecord.save({ (context) in
         _ = data(context)
     }) { (success, error) in
         completion(success,error)
     }
```

while your `self.localContext` is `mr_rootsaving`??

Quick advices:

1. Use `MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack(withAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed: dataStack)` instead of `MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack(withStoreNamed: dataStack)`. Always let MagicalRecord to handle the autoMigration for you.
2. My habit of using `MagicalRecord` is always stick with the `defaultContext` in most cases. For your use case, you really do not need to create a `self.localContext` explicitly, if you always save data using `MagicalRecord.save` (which saves data to `defaultContext`). Then you can simply use `let cart: Cart? = Cart.mr_findFirst()` to retrieve the data you need at anywhere anytime.

**Updated answer**

Thanks for updating the question @Piotr Gawłowski.

> Why there are in: context? Cause when I omit them save is not
>   performing. I've got a warnings like:NO CHANGES IN **
>   saveWithBlock:completion: ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING

`MagicalRecord.save({(context)..` creates a new context for doing the operations in the closure, and then it merges back to `defaultContext`. As I mention before, if you do not specify the context explicitly `MagicalRecord` will fall back to `defaultContext`. Thus, in the case that you didnt add 'inContext:', what happened is you created a entity in `defaultContext` inside a `MagicalRecord.save({(context)..` block. Turns out, there is not any changes made to the context of `MagicalRecord.save({(context).` (My english sucks, but i know you are clever enough to understand)

And, you can use `mr_findFirstOrCreate` initialiser

```
let addEntry: (NSManagedObjectContext) -> () = { context in
    let entry = CartEntry.mr_findFirstOrCreate(with: NSPredicate(format: "product.code == %@", productCode), in: context) {
        entry.quantity = NSNumber.init(value: (entry.quantity?.intValue)! + 1)
        entry.product = Product.mr_findFirst(with: NSPredicate(format: "code == %@", productCode), in: context)
        entry.code = productCode
        entry.cart = Cart.mr_findFirst(in: context)
}
```

Get to the point, so basically the `add` and `fetch` operations all working fine right? The problem left is the `deletion`. First of all, **Attempt 2**  is the context problem I mentioned above.

So lets focus on

> Effect 1: Completions block returns success = true, error = nil Right after this operations we're refreshing cart with  let cart: Cart? = Cart.mr_findFirst() - cart.entries field got 2 CartEntry objects ignoring fact that I just deleted one. What is more app crashes because received entry (one that supposed to be deleted) do not have related Product. CoreDataEditor shows only 1 entry. After restarting applications cart is once again correct - got only 1 entry, without data I just deleted.

1. Your `delete` call seems alright
2. App crashes is a good sign of you actually DELETED the entry
3. You relaunched the app, and there is only 1 entry left, proves your
   delete statement done its job

(Did you use the `CoreDataEditor` to double check the result?)

**So we can confirm all other parts is working , the only problem seems to be you didn't handle the datasource change properly. Are you using a `UITableView`? do you extend your class with `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and implement the delegate method?**

Please show us the code of that part. (the ViewController you use to display data).

Comment: Will try this tomorrow.
Additional thing I noticed - If my Cart got only one CartEntry everything works fine - it deletes it and is finding new cart without entries. However with multiple CartEntries it fails :(

Comment: what do your mean by `it fails`? it crashes or it shows zero record while you are expecting there are some?

Comment: Let me put it this way, your `save` and `delete` operations are working fine, and most importantly these two operations are working in the SAME context(`defaultContext`). So, you DID save the records, and your DID DELETE them. The problem is your `mr_findFirst` is querying in a different context (`rootSaving`). Thats why you didn't get what you expected.

Comment: I understood this part. However:
1. Removed context totally and allowied to handle it by default. In effect it's not saving nor deleting data.
2. By fail I mean - fetching data back gives me cart with 2 entries instead of 1, despite completion block with true as success and despite the fact that core data editor shows correct value - one entity.

Comment: I will take a look of `CoreDataEditor` tomorrow. Does it tell your which context do your data saved to? And can you also show us the fetch function call you used for `fetching data back gives me cart with 2 entries instead of 1`. That would help :)

Comment: I've just edited the whole main question describing situation step by step. Maybe now you'll be able to help me somehow.

Comment: I'm totally sure that dataSource is ok. In reload I'm calling getCartMehod which use `let cart: Cart? = Cart.mr_findFirst()` and I put a breakpoint there. Printing entity results Cart with 2 entries but one entry (one that I was removing) have no reference to product. I'm totally sure that dataSource is trying to fetch data back and verified it using breakpoint && printing values.

Comment: that's weird! the `findFirst()` should return one `Cart` object only? Are you calling `findAll()`?

Comment: Found the problem! Delete rule on `CartEntry.cart` was `No Action` instead of `Nullify`. Damm it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138916/discussion-between-piotr-gawlowski-and-pang-ho-ming).